# Construir un datatable a partir de otros datatables

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net, windows-forms

Imaginaos que tenemos 3 `datatables`, cada uno con un número de filas diferente,

Por ejemplo:

```
DATATABLE A
fila 1 - "a1"
fila 2 - "a2"

DATATABLE B
fila 1 - "b1"
fila 2 - "b2"
fila 3 - "b3"

DATATABLE C
fila 1 - "c1"
fila 2 - "c2"
```

¿Como puedo construir un método en C# o VB.NET que me devuelva otro `DataTable` con un campo que incluya una fila de cada uno de los 3 `datatables` con todas las combinaciones posibles?

Es decir, yo quiero obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
DATATABLE RESULTANTE
fila 1 "a1b1c1"
fila 2 "a1b1c2"
fila 3 "a1b2c1"
fila 4 "a1b2c2"
fila 5 "a1b3c1"
fila 6 "a1b3c2"
fila 7 "a2b1c1"
fila 8 "a2b1c2"
fila 9 "a2b2c1"
fila 10 "a2b2c2"
fila 11 "a2b3c1"
fila 12 "a2b3c2"
```

Si os dais cuenta, las filas resultantes son el resultado de multiplicar el números de filas de cada datatable (a*b*c), pero lo que no consigo es hacer un método que de como resultado lo expuesto. Imagino que hay que usar recursividad, pero por más vueltas que le doy no lo consigo.

Quiero que el método valga para más combinaciones, es decir, que no le importe realmente el número de tablas implicadas ni el número de filas en cada tabla, el método debe ser capaz de obtener todas las combinaciones posibles.

Comment: un for dentro de otro for dentro de otro for. haz pruebas y si no lo consigues te ayudaremos a buscar donde puede estar el error.

Comment: Si, con for anidados se podría hacer, pero sería si fuera un número de tablas y filas fijo, pero como anido yo más o menos "fors" cuando sean más o menos tablas?, tiene que haber otra solución y creo que parte de elaborar métodos recursivos... pero... no caigo, yo de todas formas sigo dándole vueltas, si encontrara una solución, la expongo aquí.

Comment: Hola, te invito a que repases el concepto de recursividad, al final del la consulta tendras en la propiedad .Count el numero de tablas que has recuperado, una vez tienes ese numero, con una funcion recursiva puedes hacer lo que te indico, por ejemplo este link te puede servir: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/csharpya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=175&inicio=40

Comment: Apoyo el comentario de @Veelicus, con recursividad puedes realizarlo para n tablas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una cosa así te puede servir, puedes cambiar el objeto string a cualquier objeto que necesites y usar la operativa que necesites implementar dentro del segundo for:

```
    public static List<string> gComb(List<List<string>> list)
    {
        List<string> res = new List<string>();
        List<string> first = list.First();
        List<List<string>> aux = list.Skip(1).ToList();

        if (list.Count > 1)
        {
            foreach (string s in gComb(aux))
            {
                foreach (string st in first)
                {
                    res.Add(st + ", " + s);
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
        else {
            return list.First();
        }
    }
```

Usa linQ y recursividad.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque la pregunta de por si no muestra mucho esfuerzo, voy a tratar de dar una respuesta ya que me parece que es interesante el tema.

Lo que buscas en matemáticas se llama [Producto Cartesiano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_cartesiano) y en SQL Cross Join, y siendo conocido el número de tablas es sencillo de resolver utilizando linq:

```
var producto = 
from primero in s1 
from segundo in s2 
from tercero in s3 
select new[] {first, second, third};
```

Esto realiza el producto cartesiano de 3 `IEnumerables`.

Cuando el nº de listado de entradas es desconocido, la cosa se complica pero mediante Linq tambien es posible hacerlo. Añado un ejemplo a continuación que que hace uso de un método de extensión para realizar el producto cartesiano de un nº desconocido de,en este ejemplo, arrays:

**Metodo de extension**

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ProductoCartesiano<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> secuencias)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    foreach (var secuencia in secuencias)
    {
        var s = secuencia; 
        // usando SelectMany
        resultado = resultado.SelectMany(s1 => s, (s1, s2) => (s1.Concat(new[] { s2 }))).ToArray(); //lambda

        //Usando Linq
        //resultado =
        //from seq in resultado
        //from item in s
        //select secuencia.Concat(new[] { item }).ToArray();
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

**Ejemplo**

```
string[] data1 = new string[2] { "a1", "a2" };
string[] data2 = new string[3] { "b1", "b2", "b3" };
string[] data3 = new string[2] { "c1", "c2" };

List<string[]> listaDatos = new List<string[]>();
listaDatos.Add(data1);
listaDatos.Add(data2);
listaDatos.Add(data3);

var productoCartesiano = listaDatos.ProductoCartesiano().Select(x=>String.Join(",",x)).ToList();
```

Para finalizar, no quiero atribuirme el mérito de esta solución, yo solo he adaptado un poco el código. El cerebro es el señor Eric Lippert y lo explica perfectamente en [su Blog de MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/)

Comment: Muchas gracias Pikoh, creo que has podido dar en el clavo, aplico la solución y contaré si fue satisfactoria, aunque la pinta es excelente, si señor.